# Setting up multiple sites in Apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I have the following host file entries on Ubuntu 14 machine running apache

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.20.32.20 library.myDNSname.org
10.20.32.20 library-intra.myDNSname.org
10.20.32.20 mtf
```

And also

```
sudo a2ensite library
sudo a2ensite mtf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now when I browse the site.. I can only access library.myDNSname.org page. 
But When I

```
a2dissite library
```

I can access the mtf site. 
Please note both site has been added to the sites-available. 
Any Idea how I might run both site on the same server?
Thanks for input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would have been more helpful if you had included your apache sites configuration and also how you are accessing your site (whether by ip or hostname).

If you are accessing your site by an ip then it will just select the default vhost which is the first vhost definition in the configuration file. For more info you can check out Apache's [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html).

Please try to access the sites with hostnames and post errors in comments when you tried to access mtf site for the first time.

Comment: Hi Kumar. Thanks for your reply. I am acessing the site via IP because it is a cloud enviroment at google cloud I am using for testing. I will read your input and do some twiking.

Comment: I have not seen a solution, where 1 single ip is used for mutiple sites.. I need to use IP Only .. is this possible?

Comment: If you have already made entry in your host file then you can use the host  name to access your site. If you still want to use ip only to access your site then you can configure your virtual hosts on different ports instead of default port 80 and access them by ip:port combination.